# WPF Vector based interface

Tags: .net, wpf

I'm working on a new C# application using WPF. I was under the impression that WPF was vector based and that text/buttons would be drawn in a resolution independent way. When running my application it’s fairly obvious that my application isn’t being drawn using vectors. Some of the text gets fairly blocky, and when using the windows magnifying glass you can see rough edges on everything.

Is there something special I need to do  in my application to turn vector drawing on? Or is something wrong with my specific machine? (I'm running Windows Vista x64 with the latest graphics drivers)

Comment: I'd also suggest posting a screenshot showing the blockiness you're seeing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Mangifier accessibility tool in Windows Vista ***used*** to be WPF aware. If you zoomed WPF content you would see a sharp magnified version of the app - demonstrating that WPF is indeed vector based.

Tim Sneath, a technology evanglist with Microsoft, [blogged about this in 2006](http://blogs.msdn.com/tims/archive/2006/04/04/568648.aspx):

[image]

**6/25/2011:** Original image gone. Replaced with another image showing same effect.

Greg Schechter [answers some commenters on this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/greg_schechter/archive/2008/05/12/gpu-accelerated-custom-effects-for-wpf.aspx), explaining that magnifier no longer has this trick. Magnifier would specially detect WPF applications, and know how to ask them to render themselves scaled. They removed a dependancy on WPF in magnifier. It seems that magnifier had a dependancy on something in WPF that they wanted to take away or depricate:

> Both 'bp' and 'Joseph Cooney' have
> noticed that magnification of WPF
> content using the built in OS
> Magnifier no longer does resolution
> independent zoom of content.
>
> That observation is correct.
>
> As a result of a series of changes
> that are too numerous to describe
> here, the OS magnifier is no longer
> "WPF-aware", and does bitmap scaling
> just like it does of other content.
> Although we do lose this feature, we
> believe that without the dependencies
> that enabled Magnifier to work in a
> WPF-specific way, we can be more agile
> in what we provide to WPF customers
> moving forward.
>
> Note that the above is *only* about
> out-of-process magnification.  When
> you do zooming (via scaling) within
> your own WPF application, the
> rendering continues to be
> re-rasterized at the higher scale, so
> everything remains smooth in that most
> common scenario.  This change is
> strictly about using the external
> magnifier.

So the magnifier used to have it, but no longer.

---

In the the Channel 9 video "[Greg Schechter: Windows Presentation Foundation(WPF) Architecture](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Greg-Schechter-Windows-Presentation-FoundationWPF-Architecture)", Greg Schechter talked about how Magnifier used to provide this functionality.

Magnifier and DWM worked together. Magnifier modified the DWM scene graph to make it's client area actually point to the desktop root of the scene graph. DWM then knew the magnifier was there and knew how to avoid that horrible "pointing a camcorder at a television showing the camcorder" effect.

---

**Edit**: 9/7/2018. From [Ian Griffiths' answer:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4300228/12597)

> Back when Vista first shipped, and when WPF was on version 3.0,
> zooming with the built-in magnifier would actually do vector-based
> scaling.
>
> This stopped working when WPF 3.5 service pack 1 shipped. (It worked
> in 3.5 before sp1.) The reason it worked before then is that the DWM
> (Desktop Window Manager) - the part of Windows responsible for
> presenting everything you see on screen - uses MILCORE.DLL to do its
> rendering. Version 3.0 and 3.5 of WPF also used this same component to
> render - this meant that all WPF content was native content, so to
> speak. (In fact, on Windows XP, which doesn't have the DWM,
> MILCORE.DLL is something that WPF puts on your system for its own
> benefit. But it's built into Vista and Windows 7.) When WPF was using
> MILCORE.DLL to render on Vista, any effects applied by the DWM such as
> scaling would also apply in the way you want to WPF - it really did
> scale without pixelating.
>
> Unfortunately, this is no longer the case. And the reason is that WPF
> started adding new rendering features. In 3.5 sp1, the new feature in
> question was support for custom pixel shaders. To enable that,
> Microsoft had to release an update to the MIL. (The Media Integration
> Layer - the bit that does the actual rendering.) However, they weren't
> really in a position to update MILCORE.DLL, because that's part of
> Windows - it's how everything you see on screen gets to be on screen.
> Releasing a new version of MILCORE.DLL effectively means pushing out
> an update to Windows. The release schedule for Windows is independent
> of that for .NET, and so the only way the WPF team could reasonably
> add new features was to ship a new MIL. (In theory they could have
> done it via Windows Update, but since WPF is now owned by a different
> division of Microsoft than Windows, that sort of thing doesn't seem to
> happen in practice.)
>
> As of .NET 3.5 sp1, the MIL is in a different DLL called
> wpf_gfx_vXXXX.dll where vXXXX is the version number. In .NET 4.0, it's
> wpf_gfx_v0400.dll.
>
> The upside is that WPF gets to add new rendering features with each
> new version, without needing Windows itself to be updated. The
> downside is that WPF's rendering is no longer as tightly integrated
> with Windows as it was briefly back when Vista shipped. And the upshot
> is, as you've seen, that magnifying is not as much fun as it used to
> be.

Answer (score 0):

The magnifying glass in Vista isn't particularly clever. It just blows up the already rasterized image from your screen. To see that a text box is actually vector based, try [adjusting your DPI settings](http://www.lawfirmsoftware.com/support/change_dpi_settings_vista.htm).

**EDIT:** From the comments, it seems like the magnifying glass in Vista is supposed to do vector scaling after all. It certainly doesn't on this computer (Vista 32-bit), so I may be having the same issues. DPI scaling works, though...

Comment: Actually, the magnifying glass in XP isn't particularly clever. The Vista one is supposed to do correct scaling of vector graphics, and has when I've tried it.

Comment: The Vista magnifier does do correct vector scaling. I've seen it before in a WPF application, I'm just not sure why it isn't working in mine.

Comment: Really? The magnifying glass on this computer (Vista 32-bit) does not scale my WPF apps correctly. I always assumed it was because it didn't support it, but I may be experiencing the same issue as OP then...