# Acrylic material in win32 app

Tags: uwp, dwm, acrylic-material, fluent-design

Microsoft recently revealed their new "fluent" design langauge, and one part of it is the ["acrylic" material](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/uwp/style/acrylic). This effect makes an element transparent and blurs the background. It can either be applied to a window, such that parts of underlying windows shine though (background acrylic), or to individual elements in the window, so other controls shine through (in-app acrylic). It is conceptually and visually very similar to vibrancy on macOS.

It is implemented as a special Brush in XAML, but I wonder it there is a way to use it (background acrylic) in a regular Win32 app? The effect looks very similar to the blur applied to start menu and taskbar (which is handled by [SetWindowCompositionAttribute](http://withinrafael.com/adding-the-aero-glass-blur-to-your-windows-10-apps/)) which leads me to believe that it might be activatable by a similar flag.

A subquestion: I wonder how it is implemented? Is it just a flag that you can set on a window, and then applied in the DWM (like SetWindowCompositionAttribute, or like Aero Glass in Vista and 7)? Or does UWP have some kind of control over the DWM, and can set shaders to control how it is rendered? Under Vista, when DWM was first introduced, it had common code with WPF, and it actually shared the (DirectX-like) buffers and scene-graph, so tricks like that were possible. The magifier utility could [magnify WPF apps sharply like vector images](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1070340/143091), but that functionality was lost later. The way MS presents "acrylic" on that page (as different layers, and implemented as an XAML brush), leads me to think that you'd somehow have to inject layers into the DWM scenegraph, which would make it harder or impossible to use from Win32.

Answer (score 10):

[Sciter 4.2](https://sciter.com/sciter-4-2-support-of-acrylic-theming/) adds support of acrylic backgrounds (on Windows and MacOS):

Acrylic theme and UWP alike controls (CSS styled) in Sciter:

[image: Acrylic theme and UWP alike controls in Sciter]

uSciter demo browser, Windows:

[image: uSciter demo browser, Windows]

uSciter demo browser, MacOS:

[image: uSciter demo browser, MacOS]

Sciter on Windows is an ordinary Win32 application (not UWP).

In order to render that blurbehind it does the following:

Creates window with `WS_EX_NOREDIRECTIONBITMAP` ex flag.

Calls:

```
struct WINDOWCOMPOSITIONATTRIBDATA {
  WINDOWCOMPOSITIONATTRIB dwAttrib;
  PVOID                   pvData;
  SIZE_T                  cbData;
};

enum ACCENT_STATE {
  ACCENT_DISABLED = 0,
  ACCENT_ENABLE_GRADIENT = 1,
  ACCENT_ENABLE_TRANSPARENTGRADIENT = 2,
  ACCENT_ENABLE_BLURBEHIND = 3,
  ACCENT_ENABLE_ACRYLIC_BLURBEHIND = 4,
  ACCENT_INVALID_STATE = 5
};

ACCENT_POLICY accent = { ACCENT_ENABLE_ACRYLIC_BLURBEHIND, 0, clr, 0 };
WINDOWCOMPOSITIONATTRIBDATA data;
data.dwAttrib = WCA_ACCENT_POLICY;
data.pvData = &accent;
data.cbData = sizeof(accent);
SetWindowCompositionAttribute(get_hwnd(), &data);
```

Where clr is AGBR, something like `0xCC000000` for dark blur behind background.

Renders content using Direct2D surface set on DirectComposition Visual attached to window's swap chain using `IDXGIFactory2::CreateSwapChainForComposition`

Details of all this are a bit murky and COM-verbose, sigh (I am an author of the Sciter).

At least you shall use Direct2D for drawing in order to render something like this.

Comment: It makes sense to mention that this way doesn't work in Windows10 1903+.

Answer (score 3):

I just found this project that bring acrylic to WPF : https://github.com/bbougot/AcrylicWPF

It seems your hypothesis were good. It uses SetWindowsCompositionAttribute and apply a shader on it.

Comment: It's not the real acrylic effect of Windows 10 Fluent Design System. It uses its own shader effect which named Noise.fx and runs on its own process. The blur effect is `SetWindowsCompositionAttribute` but it is not recommended. It is just simulating the acrylic brush of Fluent Design System.

Answer (score 3):

The Acrylic Effect Sciter uses is by using SetWindowCompositionAttribute(),currently it is laggy, but I came up with another way to implement same acrylic effect but a different method.

Check out this [Win32 Acrylic Effect using IDComposition and Direct2D](https://github.com/Extrimis/Win32-Acrylic-Effect)

Comment: Pretty neat, and not laggy at all! I wonder if `DwmCreateSharedMultiWindowVisual` samples the underlying pixels and pulls them into your process, or if it merely tells the DWM to composite this window ontop of the background? I remember old Aero just composited all the (alpha transparent) windows in the DWM, whereas the documentation for Acrylic said somewhere that it must apply blur for *security reasons* because the background bitmap is composited *in your process*.

Comment: They can also hide the window using dwm attributes

Answer (score 2):

It's effects are created using the Lower level XAML Composition APIs, which uses UWP's XAML Compositor, so I would say that I doubt you will be able to achieve this natively in Win32. If you really want it, you can either take your app across the Desktop Bridge, and convert the UI, or mimic the effects with the technology available today. (Browsers such as Chrome, manage to use bring the Window Chrome further into their app, although I'm not sure how you would achieve the acrylic effect).

Comment: "I doubt you will be able to achieve this natively in Win32" - it is doable, see my answer.

Comment: This is now possible by using the Desktop Bridge and XAML Islands.