# Is there a Win32 API for enabling Windows 1803's translucent title bar?

Tags: winapi, windows-10

Windows 10 version 1803 adds translucency to some UWP apps, including title bars.

Is there API to get use this translucent title bar in Win32 apps?

(I know about owner drawn frames, that's not what I'm asking for. But I am totally open to nasty hacks involving Windows Runtime APIs.)

Comment: [Acrylic material](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/acrylic) for UWP applications. I'm unaware of a Windows API call that produces the same effect on a native Win32 window.

Comment: UWP leans pretty heavily on DirectComposition.  This smells like IDCompositionDevice3::CreateGaussianBlurEffect(), hard to be sure from a screen-shot.

Comment: Asked before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44000217/mimicking-acrylic-in-a-win32-app

Comment: That does seem to be it @HansPassant, good answers there too. The title bar issue itself is only shortly addressed but there are some pointers.

Comment: Since Windows 8 [I use this DLL](http://www.glass8.eu/download) to restore the Windows Vista/7 Aero Glass for title bar.